# Time response analysis of a 1st order system with PID feedback control loop and step input using python

Tags: control-theory, python

I am new to control theory. Since I don't have a Matlab license, I am working with python to test my understanding of various control theory concepts. I am using python's [control system library](https://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.0/index.html). Recently I have started working on time response analysis of 1st order closed loops systems. I have written the below program to plot the step responses.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

import control as ctl 
from control.matlab import step

import numpy as np 

T = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
s = ctl.tf("s")

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left = 0.1,bottom=0.4)

# plt.axis ([0,10,0,2])

pid,=plt.plot(T,T,color="green",lw=2,label="PID")
p,=plt.plot(T,T,color="blue",lw=2,label="P")
pd,=plt.plot(T,T,color="red",lw=2,label="PD")
pi,=plt.plot(T,T,color="black",lw=2,label="PI")
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Response')
plt.title('1st order system with various feedback controls')


axSliderKp = plt.axes([0.1,0.3,0.8,0.05])
axSliderTi =plt.axes([0.1,0.2,0.8,0.05])
axSliderTd =plt.axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.05])

Kp_Slider = Slider(axSliderKp,"Kp",valmin =0.0001,valmax=100,valinit=100,valfmt = "%1.5f",valstep=0.01,color="cyan",closedmin=False)
Ti_Slider = Slider(axSliderTi,"Ti",valmin =0.0001,valmax=10,valinit=1,valfmt = "%1.1f",valstep=0.01,color="magenta",closedmin=False)
Td_Slider = Slider(axSliderTd,"Td",valmin =0.0001,valmax=1,valinit =1,valfmt = "%1.5f",valstep=0.01,color ="yellow",closedmin=False)

def val_update(val):
    Kp = Kp_Slider.val
    Ti = Ti_Slider.val 
    Td = Td_Slider.val

    PID_part = Kp*(1+1/(Ti*s) +(Td*s))
    P_Part = Kp
    PI_Part = Kp*(1+1/(Ti*s))
    PD_Part = Kp*(1+(Td*s))

    plant = 1/(s+3)

    PID_Plant =  PID_part*plant

    P_Plant = ctl.feedback(P_Part*plant)
    PI_Plant = ctl.feedback(PI_Part*plant)
    PD_Plant = ctl.feedback(PD_Part*plant)

    PID_res,t = step(PID_Plant)
    P_res , t = step(P_Plant)
    PI_res, t = step(PI_Plant)
    PD_res,t =step(PD_Plant)

    pid.set_ydata(PID_res)

    pid.set_xdata(t)

    p.set_ydata(P_res)

    p.set_xdata(t)

    pi.set_ydata(PI_res)

    pi.set_xdata(t)

    pd.set_ydata(PD_res)

    pd.set_xdata(t)

    plt.draw()

Kp_Slider.on_changed(val_update)
Ti_Slider.on_changed(val_update)
Td_Slider.on_changed(val_update)


plt.show()
```

This program takes inputs for `Kp`, `Ti`, and `Td` using sliders on matplotlib plot. I am able to get the plots for P, PI, and PD controls on this plot. But for some weird reason, the PID control giving the absurd plot for almost all the `Kp`, `Ti`, and `Td` that I have tried. Below is the plot for some values of PID.

[image: The plot of P, PI,PD, and PID controls of a closed-loop 1st order system]

[image: Zoomed-in plot]

Why is the PID plot the way it is? Is the PID making the system unstable?

And also at `Td=0`, the `P` plot and `PD` plot are matching with each other. Then shouldn't the `PID` and `PI` plots also match at `Td=0`? Refer to the below plot.

[image: Plot at Td=0]

I have been trying to understand this and make sense of it for the last couple of days. I have no luck so far. Can any of you kindly help me understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am extremely dumb. I made a mistake in the program. I failed to compute the feedback for the PID system.

This line:

```
PID_Plant =  PID_part*plant
```

should be changed to:

```
PID_Plant =  ctl.feedback(PID_part*plant)
```

Now I am getting the correct (I hope) plots.

[image: P, PI, PD and PID plots of 1st order closed-loop system with unit step input]